# Run function on columns AND keep rows

Tags: r, function

I have two data.frames (`df1` and `df2`). Each df contains three columns. I'm going to use `df1$This` to find perfect and partial matches in `df2$That`. The problem is both columns contain duplicates. I have therefore created `df1$id` and `df2$ids` to give each row a unique identifier.

To solve my first problem I first fetch the strings that are perfect matches, and then the partial matches by calculating Levenshtein distance. I found a function [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-data-sets-based-on-partially-matched-data-elements/) and adjusted it to my data and desired output.

```
signature = function(x){
  sig=paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(tolower(x)," "))),collapse='')
  return(sig)
}


partialMatch = function(x,y,levDist=0.05){
  xx=data.frame(sig=sapply(x, signature),row.names=NULL)
  yy=data.frame(sig=sapply(y, signature),row.names=NULL)
  xx$raw=x
  yy$raw=y
  xx=subset(xx,subset=(sig!=''))
  xy=merge(xx,yy,by='sig',all=T)
  matched=subset(xy,subset=(!(is.na(raw.x)) & !(is.na(raw.y))))
  matched$type="Perfect"
  todo=subset(xy,subset=(is.na(raw.y)),select=c(sig,raw.x))
  colnames(todo)=c('sig','raw')
  todo$partials= as.character(sapply(todo$sig, agrep, yy$sig,max.distance = levDist,value=T))
  todo=merge(todo,yy,by.x='partials',by.y='sig',all=T)
  partial.matched=subset(todo,subset=(!(is.na(raw.x)) & !(is.na(raw.y))),select=c("sig","raw.x", "raw.y"))
  partial.matched$type="Partial"
  matched=rbind(matched,partial.matched)
  matched=subset(matched,select=c("raw.x", "raw.y","type"))

  return(matched)
}
```

I call this function by using `df3 <- partialMatch(df1$This, df2$That)` which results in a df containing `raw.x (df1$This)`, `raw.y (df2$That)` and type `(Perfect/Partial)`. My question pretty much is if I can call the function on these two columns but *keep* the data in the other columns for the end results. Like `df3 <- partialMatch(df$This, df$That)` AND bring each row for each column. So that my data goes from

```
df1
This    id    detail
ab c    1     male
a c d   2     male
a d d   3     female
ab c    4     female

df2
That   ids   details
abc    x     strong
a c d  y     weak
aff    z     maniac
ab c   k     lord
```

To

```
df3
This  That    type    id  detail ids  details
ab c   abc    perfect 1   male   x    strong
ab c   ab c   perfect 1   male   k    lord
ab c   abc    perfect 4   female x    strong
ab c   ab c   perfect 4   female k    lord
a c d  a c d  perfect  2  male   y    weak
```

Or do I have to edit this within the function? I can't merge after I've run the function because of the duplicate-problem.

Maybe `apply` is the right way to go? I tried the following, which obviously didn't work. Posted for inspiration.

```
apply(df1[,c('id','detail')], 1, partialMatch(df1$This, df2$That))
```

Comment: This question would be a lot easier if there was some sample data (be it real or fake), because the code is not that easy to understand. Edit: My first guess would be that you should supply the whole data frames to the function, and then simply add `sig` to those instead of creating `xx` and `yy`, and then merge them. But again, this would be much much clearer if you could provide some sample.

Comment: Thanks for input. Updated with a sample.

Comment: I get following order when loading the data frames. `testMatch <- partialMatch()
 
 Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match 
4 stop("numbers of columns of arguments do not match") 
3 rbind(deparse.level, ...) 
2 rbind(matched, partial.matched) 
1 partialMatch()`

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am not sure if this works 100%, but it should give you an idea of what you need to change in order to integrate whatever functionality you want.

It's just a matter of rewriting the function a bit:

```
partialMatch = function(df1, col1, df2, col2, levDist=0.05){
  x <- df1[,col1]  
  y <- df2[,col2]
  xx <- data.frame(df1, 
                   sig = gsub("[[:space:]]", "", x),
                   raw = x,
                   row.names=NULL)
  yy <- data.frame(df2, 
                   sig = gsub("[[:space:]]", "", y),
                   raw = y,
                   row.names=NULL)
  xx <- subset(xx,subset=(sig!=''))
  xy <- merge(xx,yy,by='sig',all=T)
  xy$type <- NA
  xy$type[!(is.na(xy$raw.x) | is.na(xy$raw.y))] <- "Perfect"
  todo <- subset(xy,subset=(is.na(raw.y)),select=c(sig,raw.x))
  colnames(todo) <- c('sig','raw')
  todo$partials <- as.character(sapply(todo$sig, agrep, yy$sig,max.distance = levDist,value=T))
  if (nrow(todo) > 0) {
    todo <- merge(todo,xy,by.x='partials',by.y='sig',all=T)
    partial.matched <- subset(todo,subset=(!(is.na(raw.x)) & !(is.na(raw.y))))
    partial.matched$type <- "Partial"
    partial.matched[,col2] <- partial.matched$raw
    partial.matched <- partial.matched[,!names(partial.matched) %in% c("raw","partials")]
    xy <- rbind(xy,partial.matched)
  }
  xy <- subset(xy,select=c(col1,col2,"type","id","detail","ids","details"))
  xy <- xy[!(is.na(xy[,col1]) | is.na(xy[,col2])),]
  rownames(xy) <- NULL
  return(xy)

}

partialMatch(df1, "This", df2, "That")
#    This  That    type id detail ids details
# 1  ab c   abc Perfect  1   male   x  strong
# 2  ab c  ab c Perfect  1   male   k    lord
# 3  ab c   abc Perfect  4 female   x  strong
# 4  ab c  ab c Perfect  4 female   k    lord
# 5 a c d a c d Perfect  2   male   y    weak
# 6 a c d a d d Partial  2   male   y    weak
```

Edit: Fixed the situation where there are no perfect or partial matches.

Comment: Have had this error before. Dunno why it is. `Error in $<-.data.frame(`*tmp*`, "type", value = "Perfect") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

Comment: Hmm I know why it is. Give me a second to create a workaround.

Comment: @user3471881 I think I fixed it, can you retry?

Comment: With above error is now `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "type", value = "Partial") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0`

Comment: I'm really thankful for your help thus far btw @Laterow. I looked at your changes, is it right to assume the error in the first case (before your changes) is thrown because of `non Perfect matches` and thus the new error is thrown because of `non Partial matches`?

Comment: @user3471881 Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to do. It turns out that I somewhere added `& !is.na(sig)`, but I am not sure why I did that. I think I made that change in a previous version, and then forgot to take it out in the new one... Messy coding. Anyway, I validated it and it should work now, can you try?

Comment: It should probably be working, but for some reason I think agrep is getting pissed off. I kept an eye out and this is not a memory issue on my side. `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : regcomp error:  'Out of memory' 
4 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
3 lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
2 sapply(todo$sig, agrep, yy$sig, max.distance = levDist, value = T)`

Comment: Googling around, this does seem to be an agrep problem. I simply do not know enough about agrep to help any further. Sorry!